# „etwas beschäftigt jmdn.“ vs. „sich mit etwas beschäftigen“

Tags: verb, verb-usage

I was wondering if there is a difference in meaning between these two structures:

> - Ich beschäftige mich mit diesem Problem.
> - Dieses Problem beschäftigt mich.

Is there a difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Ich beschäftige mich mit diesem Problem" means I actively deal with the problem, I made a conscious decision to try to find a solution.

"Dieses Problem beschäftigt mich" can mean the problem is currently occupying me - more or less the same meaning like above, just in a passive wording - but it can also mean it bothers me - I'm currently doing other things but thoughts about this problem keep coming to my mind.